# Javascript/ HTML Transferring form Controls to submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, getelementbyid

I have been attempting to create a form with 5 text boxes, 1 drop down and a text area. My intention is simple; select an option from the Drop down( except the first i.e "--Select--"), enter the contents into the text box and text area. Once I click submit all the above entered information should get appended to specific links that is hard coded into each drop down option.

My challenge here is that when I click submit, the controls are no getting passed to the new form i.e. the desired page opens,but the form fields do not get entered. I have cross verified and confirmed that the ids are correct.. I'm guessing that i have made a mistake in the validation. Kindly point out my mistake..

Javascript Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function dpdown(form)
{
    var a="&name="+document.getElementById('name').value;  //textbox
    var b="&job_id="+document.getElementById('job_id').value;//textbox
    var c="&major"+document.getElementById("major').value;//textbox
    var d="&native="+document.getElementById('native').value;//textbox
    var e="&age="+document.getElementById('age').value;//textbox
    var f="&details="+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('details').value);//textarea
    var i, counter = 0;
    var ddl = document.getElementById("jobs");//dropdown
    var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
    for(var i=0; i < obj.options.length; i++)
         {   
              if(obj.options[i].selected) // to check if the person has chosen a suitable degree
                    if (selectedValue == "selectdegree")
                     {
                       alert("Please select your correct degree");
                     } 
                     else
                     {
                       ++counter;
                       window.open('https://'+form.elements[i].value+a+b+c+d+e+f,'_blank'); // when the submit button is clicked, all the above fields should get appended to a preset link which has been hardcoded for each degree.
                     }
          }
}

function cleartext()// to clear the form (works correctly)
{
 document.form.details.value='';
}
```

HTML Code

```
    <form onsubmit="dpdown(this); return false;"> // at the beginning of the form
'
'
'
'
 <input type="submit" value=" Create form" /> // not working
 <input type='reset' value='Clear Ticket' name='reset' onclick="return resetForm(this.form);cleartext();"> // works well
```

Comment: Where `obj` comes from?

Comment: I think you can't open new browser windows along with values. So I think you first need to put entered values into cookies and then you can resolve values on page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check it.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        function dpdown(){
            var a="&name="+document.getElementById('name').value;  //textbox
            var b="&job_id="+document.getElementById('job_id').value;//textbox
            var c="&major"+document.getElementById('major').value;//textbox
            var d="&native="+document.getElementById('native').value;//textbox
            var e="&age="+document.getElementById('age').value;//textbox
            var f="&details="+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('details').value);//textarea
            var i, counter = 0;
            var ddl = document.getElementById("jobs");//dropdown
            var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
            for(var i=0; i < ddl.length; i++)
                 {   
                      if(ddl.options[i].selected) // to check if the person has chosen a suitable degree
                            if (selectedValue == "selectdegree")
                             {
                               alert("Please select your correct degree");
                             } 
                             else
                             {
                               ++counter;
                               value=ddl.options[i].value;
                               window.open('https://'+value+a+b+c+d+e+f,'_blank'); // when the submit button is clicked, all the above fields should get appended to a preset link which has been hardcoded for each degree.
                             }
                  }
        }

        function cleartext()
        {
         document.form.details.value='';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form> 
        <input type="text" id="name"/>
        <input type="text" id="job_id"/>
        <input type="text" id="major"/>
        <input type="text" id="native"/>
        <input type="text" id="age"/>
        <input type="textarea" id="details"/>
        <select id="jobs" >
        <option value="www.google.com">google</option>
        <option value="www.yahoo.com">yahoo</option>
        <option value="www.stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</option>        
        </select>
        <input type="button" value=" Create form" onclick="dpdown();"/> 
        <input type='reset' value='Clear Ticket' name='reset' onclick="return resetForm(this.form);cleartext();">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi user3875452, Thanks for the edits , the code appears to be working partially, although after removing the  'form.elements[i].value' part, the links are not getting pulled, but instead all the other fields that should get appended to the links are opening up .. any way to correct that error ?

Comment: My suggestion is assign form.elements[i] to variable and use this variable in indow.open.eg.    value="www.google.com";         window.open('https://'+value+a+b+c+d+e+f,'_blank');

Comment: to be more specific, each selection in the dropdown list has a link, when i click the an option in the dropdown and click submit, the link should open in a new page along with these appended fields... for now only the new tab is opening along with the fields, but the actual link does not open ..

Comment: Perfect it works like a charm :) I have another question regarding the drop downs.. if have another drop down menu to add, can i use the same method ? because for  the next drop down I add, the selected value should be displayed in a text box .. is this possible ?